# More division by zero in calculus (and beginning to see the light)

Tags: calculus

Making progress: let $x = 0$:

- $\frac{\sin x}x = \frac 00 = 1$
- $\frac{1-\cos x}x = \frac{1-1}0 = \frac 00 = 0$

... so at $\lim x>0$ we find that the forbidden division by zero gives us different answers even though both functions graph just fine.

Question: what other 'specimens' of this kind of thing are there?

What other answers are possible?  1, 0, ... any other answers?  Infinity?

If any number is a possible answer, then I repent of my folly and see that we really must do things the hard way: we must do these function substitutions so as to avoid the division by zero.  (Even tho the replacement function and the original graph identically.)

Comment: Be careful, it is wrong to say $\sin(x)/x = 0/0 = 1$. The correct way to say it is $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)/x=1$.

Comment: "*what other answers are possible?*"  All.  Example, replace $\sin(x)$ with $\alpha\cdot \sin(x)$ in your example for any $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ or whatever field you are working in.

Comment: Literally anything is possible when a limit approaches $\frac00$. Hence, we try to apply other tools (often L'Hospital's) to evaluate said limits.

Comment: Consider $$\frac{\sin 3x}{x}$$ as $x\to 0$.  What do you think it should be?

Comment: This is the reason why we call $\frac00$ (and its cousins) "indeterminate forms". Because we can't determine, without more information, what number they are supposed to represent. It could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the $\frac00$ form can have any sort of limit.

Consider the following functions and their limits at $0$.

- $\frac{x^2}{x^4}$ is such a form, with limit $\infty$.
- $\frac{-x^2}{x^4}$ has limit $-\infty$.
- $\frac{x^2}{x^3}$ has no limit.
- $\frac{\sin{rx}}x$ has limit $r$.

All of these functions, at $0$, have indeterminate form $\frac00$, but show that literally any possible limit can exist.

Comment: It's still beyond me to  evaluate some of those, but I get the message: my earlier idea that these '0/0' things would all have some simple resolution is shot to pieces ;-)  Thanks.

Comment: So why then does graphing software have no issue with sin(x)/x?

Comment: Graphing software just picks a lot of random points to plot, and then connects the dots. Since $0$ isn't usually picked, it isn't a problem.

Comment: So it sorta ignores the problem?  I guess then that very very strictly there IS a gap in the graph, no?

Comment: @RayAndrews Yup, graphing software just pretends its not there.

Answer (score 2):

The expressions

- $ \frac{\sin x}x = \frac 00 = 1$
- $\frac{1-\cos x}x = \frac{1-1}0 = \frac 00 = 0$

are meaningless, we should write instead

- $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}x=1$
- $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}x=0$

In general, when we face with an indeterminate form $\frac 00$ or others in a limit then we can expect any result for the limit, for example

- $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\log x=0$
- $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}x=1$
- $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^4}=\infty$

Comment: I'm only a few hours into calculus, but it had seemed at first that we were only saying that '0/0' can't be evaluated as a formality (but in practice our graphs are unbroken so it seemed *only* a formality).

Answer (score 1):

First of all 0/0 is undefined. Second limit means that when x approach les very near to the value then what happens with the function.

Take $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{x}$ for example. If u see this graph then y will be equal to 1 for every value of X except for zero. So we assume that as x approaches 0 y tends to 1.

Likewise, here limit for sin X doesn't mean that what is the value of that function when x goes to that limiting value..What it means that what value it tends to when x approaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be intrigued by the notion that $\frac{0}{0}$ gives two different answers, but $\frac{0}{0}$ gives no answer. It is simply a result that means "the answer cannot be determined." It usually indicates that the method you're using to find an answer is insufficient and that you must try some other means.

The equations you're referring to are actually limits. Specifically, they are

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

and

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}=0$$

If you attempt to solve them via direct substitution, then you will indeed get $\frac{0}{0}$, and what this means is that the method of direct substitution is not powerful enough to provide an answer for this type of problem. Therefore, you must try some other means. People have tried other means and gotten the answers $1$ and $0$, respectively.

What these equations are saying is that the outputs of the functions get closer and closer to $1$ and $0$, respectively, as the inputs to the functions get closer and closer to $0$ from both the left and the right. They do not communicate anything about the outputs of the functions whenever $x=0$. Again, they only describe the behavior of the functions as the inputs, or $x$, APPROACH $0$.

Comment: Yet I can graph sin(x)/x without difficulty.  At x=0, y=1.  My computer does not crash.  The graph shows no break.

Comment: There is no reason your computer should crash if you ask it to graph $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. There actually is a "break" in the graph, and some graphing software will show it while others don't very well. The reason some do not is because it is a break,or hole, at an infinitely small location, at the very spot where $x=0$. Sometimes you can see it if you ask the software for a table of values and plug in $x=0$ or if you hover your mouse over the point. In any case, it is fine to use pictoral graphs to guide your intuition, but i do not recommend relying on them for proving theoretical truths